# show Wordpress posts under subcategory only, not category

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using this code to display subcategory in a category

```
<?php $this_category = get_category($cat);

    $id = get_query_var('cat');
    $args = array(  'parent' => $id );
    $catdesc = $cat->category_description;
    foreach (get_categories($args) as $cat) 
:?>
<a href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat->term_id); ?>">
<?php echo ("$cat->cat_name"); ?></a>

    <?php endforeach ?>     

    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php
        get_template_part( 'content/content', get_post_format() );
    ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

The problem is that all the posts in the category display under the category and the subcategory.

But i want to display posts under that subcategory only, not in category.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this:

$category = 'Jobs';

$categoryID = get_cat_ID($category);

$subcategories = get_categories('child_of=' . $categoryID);

foreach($subcategories as $subcategory) {

   $subcategory_posts = get_posts('cat=' . $subcategory->cat_ID);

   foreach($subcategory_posts as $subcategory_post) {

           $postID = $subcat_post->ID;

           echo get_the_title($postID);
   }
}

For more details go to this https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-list-posts-by-sub-category
```